# Wrapped TouchableNativeFeedback component with View doesn't show anything on screen with flex:1 on both

Tags: react-native

The style is added to the wrapping view because `TouchableNativeFeedback` didn't work either. I have tried `alignItems`, `justifyContent`, `flexGrow` and other experimentations but still doesn't behave properly. `GridItem` style is the one I want to use but nothing shows in the screen; not even misaligned contents or something similar.

```js
const CategoryGridTile = props => {
  let TouchableCmp = TouchableOpacity;
  if (Platform.OS == 'android' && Platform.Version >= 21) {
    TouchableCmp = TouchableNativeFeedback;
  }
    
  return (
    <View style={styles.gridItem}>
      <TouchableCmp
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onPress={props.onSelect}
      >
        <View style={{ ...styles.container, ...{ backgroundColor: props.color } }}>
          <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={2}>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableCmp>
    </View>
  );
};
    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gridItem: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 15,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius:10,
    overflow:'hidden'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowRadius: 10,
    elevation: 3,
    padding: 15,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'flex-end'
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold',
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'right'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this...
TouchableCmp is working

```
const CategoryGridTile = () => {
    let TouchableCmp = TouchableOpacity;
    if (Platform.OS == 'android' && Platform.Version >= 21) {
      TouchableCmp = TouchableNativeFeedback;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.gridItem}>
        <TouchableCmp style={{flex: 1}} onPress={() => alert('onpress')}>
          <View style={{...styles.container, ...{backgroundColor: 'pink'}}}>
            <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={2}>
              text here
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableCmp>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

I've removed prop elements to check, you can add later if this works for you